# How to bypass root folder name in apache tomcat server url?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I want to access the url with out having to mention the name of the root folder in spring MVC project.

EXAMPLE:
http://localhost:8080/hospitalManagement/user**-->**http://localhost:8080/user

Do i need to make any modifications in **web.xml** file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the answer...

In Request-mapping put the value as ("/")

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String indexController(){
        logger.info("IndexController Method called");
        return "index";
    }
```

And also in web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think that those steps could help you

---

1. In your project's Properties, choose "Web Project Settings".
2. Change "Context root" to "user".
3. Choose Window > Show View > Servers.
4. Stop the server by either clicking the red square box ("Stop the
   server" tooltip) or context-click on the server listing to choose
   "Stop".
5. On the server you want to use, context-click to choose "Clean…".
6. Click OK in the confirmation dialog box.

Now you can run your app with the new "user" URL such as:

http://localhost:8080/user/

Comment: Thank you ,i should have been bit precise..[localhost:8080] should be giving the same result as [http://localhost:8080/hospitalManagement/].

Comment: If my post is the solution in your case ,please mark it as resolved